# Is the threat of thread safety of primitive types using only get or set overblown?

Tags: c++, c, thread-safety

I've been on a bit of a warpath at work for the past week about a system where on a Cortex-A9 doubles are get and set from multiple threads without a hint of thread safety.  It seems to work fine and after a bit of testing I cannot get my desktop to fail a simple test using __int128.  Are the odds of reading a wrong value non-zero?  Should the odds be significant and I'm not doing it right?

Any example code that repeatably fails on a modern x86_64 machine would be great.  But only using get/set on primitive types.

Comment: Could you provide some examples from your codebase?

Comment: Formally, the code described here has undefined behavior. One of the most frustrating symptoms of undefined behavior is that it "seems to work fine". Until, that is, you're demonstrating your new product to your most important customer and it blows up.

Comment: The problem with undefined behavior is that it's impossible to give "odds" for -- since neither the language spec nor the compiler provide any guarantees about how undefined code will behave, any behavior you observe empirically may be just happenstance, i.e. a product of your particular environment.  You could run your test for a year with no errors, only to find out that the code breaks as soon as someone changes a (seemingly) unrelated build setting, or updates to the next version of the compiler, or runs another program at the same time.  The only way to avoid the uncertainty is avoid UB.

Comment: Isn't it a bit much to ask for code that repeatably fails when talking about thread safety? Are intermittent failures not bugs? Also, why are you asking for x86 code when the production runs on ARM? By the nature of undefined behaviour, the results may well differ by architecture.

Comment: Note that there could be different errors than just reading a wrong value, like the compiler assuming that a non-atomic value is constant if it can prove there are no writes between two reads, but you are not asking about these, right? You "want" to read a value that was never written?

Comment: Pete and Jeremy, I love the perspective on this.  Gives me the vocab I was missing on the issue.

Paul,  Maybe it is.  I was hoping I could have an example I could show those not in the know quickly.  I ask about x86 because I don't always have an ARM board around but I accept your point about undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah, OK. I am not sure how complex your code is, but I experimented a little with the compiler explorer and it seems the code generated for `memory_order_relaxed` 64 bit stores is similar to non-atomic stores on x86-64 at least - so I am pretty sure in this case the danger of the hardware mixing the values up completely by itself are zero. I would worry more about the compiler starting to "optimize" in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Try running this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <array>

std::array<int, 10> sharedArray;
void taskOne()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sharedArray.size(); ++i)
        {
            sharedArray[i] = 5;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sharedArray.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (sharedArray[i] != 5)
            {
                std::cout << "ERROR";
                std::terminate();
            }
        }
    }
}

void taskTwo()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sharedArray.size(); ++i)
        {
            sharedArray[i] = 10;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1{ taskOne };
    std::thread t2{ taskTwo };
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

This printed out `ERROR` and terminated within a second on my x86_64 machine using MSVC. (On the [Ideone machine too](https://ideone.com/8j0DOr).)

Yes, the odds are non-zero, yes the odds are significant on a multi-core processor.

Comment: Do you mean that double is like 2 ints and it will be partially read once in a while?

Comment: @Yola I mean that between the setting the `int`s to `5` and checking their values they've changed to `10`.

Comment: Thanks, that i see, i mean, how is this answer related to the question?

Comment: @Yola `10` being a wrong value, as OP questions. Unless OP means to question the atomicy of those primitive types, I'd need OP to clarify that.

Comment: I am more referring to a situation where the value becomes neither the new or the old value.  It is not particularly unsafe for the controller to accept one value or the next in control.  It is more unsafe if the value goes, even momentarily, to a value completely out of character for the control.